# Good way to start communicating with a client?

Tags: c++, c, tcp, network-programming

The way my game and server work is like this:

I send messages that are encoded in a format I created. It starts with 'p' followed by an integer for the message length then the message.

ex: p3m15
The message is 3 bytes long. And it corresponds to message 15.
The message is then parsed and so forth.

It is designed for TCP potentially only sending only 1 byte (since TCP only has to send a minimum of 8 bits).

This message protocol I created is extremely lightweight and works great which is why I use it over something like JSON or other ones.

My main concern is, how should the client and the server start talking?

The server expects clients to send messages in my format. The game will always do this.

The problem I ran into was when I tested my server on port 1720. There was BitTorrent traffic and my server was picking it up. This was causing all kinds of random 'clients' to connect to my server and sending random garbage.

To 'solve' this, I made it so that the first thing a client must send me is the string "Hello Server".

If the first byte ever sent is != 'H' or if they have sent me > 12 bytes and it's != "Hello Server" then I immediately disconnect them.

This is working great. I'm just wondering if I'm doing something a bit naive or if there are more standard ways to deal with:

-Clients starting communication with server
-Clients passing Hello Server check, but somewhere along the line I get an invalid message. I can assume that my app will never send an invalid message. If it did, it would be a bug. Right now if I detect an invalid message then I disconnect the client.

I noticed BitTorrent was sending '!!BitTorrent Protocol' before each message. Should I do something like that?

Any advice on this and making it safer and more secure would be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Using ASCII to specify the message length, IMO is a bad idea. Typically the header is a fixed length, so you can always read that many bytes. Then you get the (variable) length from the header, and continue to read that many bytes to get the rest of the packet.  If it's in ASCII, how do you know how many bytes to initially read?

Comment: The port number can be usually be seen as part of the procotol. Many protocols are commonly linked to a specific port number, like HTTP (80), SMTP (25)... So you should try to use a port number not used by other applications.

Comment: Rather than filter what is unacceptable, I believe it is better practice to more rigorously define your protocol to only accept what _is_ acceptable (i.e. don't do anything to `!!BitTorrent...` since port collisions are always possible). If this is being done on top of TCP, then an admission protocol like you have explained seems to be fine. If you are working over UDP (I imagine you are not creating a new transport protocol), you will have to probably have some initialization handshake.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Doesn't make much difference to wait until your buffer contains enough bytes for the message length field (e.g. four bytes) or to wait until it contains 'p' plus some digits followed by an 'm'.

Comment: In the worst case, there is some protocol `X1` out there in the wild that some client `Y` uses on your own port `Z`, that looks similar enough to your own protocol `X2` that distinguishing between the two programatically is intractible; only higher-level mechanisms such as identity authentication can filter this out. i.e. if protocol `X1` happens to be close enough to `X2` to not break your system, is there still a problem? Otherwise, can you improve your system so that it is not? My point is that you can't fix everything by adding sentinel values and header frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps a magic number field embedded in your message.

```
struct Message
{
    ...
    unsigned magic_number = 0xbadbeef3;
    ...
};
```

so first thing you do after receive something, is checking whether the magic_number field is 0xbadbeef3.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I design protocols with a header something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t    signature;
    uint32_t    length;
    uint32_t    message_num;
} header_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t    foo;
} message13_t;
```

Sending a message:

```
message13_t msg;
msg.foo = 0xDEADBEEF;

header_t hdr;
hdr.signature = 0x4F4C494D;         // "MILO"
hdr.length = sizeof(message13_t);
hdr.message_num = 13;

// Send the header
send(s, &hdr, sizeof(hdr), 0);

// Send the message data
send(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
```

Receiving a message:

```
header_t hdr;
char* buf;

// Read the header - all messages always have this
recv(s, &hdr, sizeof(hdr), 0);

// allocate a buffer for the rest of the message
buf = malloc(hdr.length);

// Read the rest of the message
recv(s, buf, hdr.length, 0);
```

This code is obviously devoid of error-checking or making sure all data has been sent/received.

Comment: I hope your real code is not as devoid of efforts to ensure a certain byte order as this sample code is (I'd expect a `htonl` call or similiar somewhere). ;-)